# How do I run a Powershell script remotely as admin? (PsExec)

Tags: windows, powershell, psexec

I would like to use PsExec to run a Powershell script (on a server) remotely on a computer as an administrator.

Unfortunately this does not work:
psexec -s -i \computername Powershell \server\CNC_install.ps1 -Force

It keeps returning me "Access denied".

Comment: Access denied implies that its not accepting your credentials - have you tried supplying them for psexec with `-u username -p password`?

Comment: Hello, I have just tried:
psexec -s -i -u username -p password \\computer Powershell \\server\CNC_install.ps1 -Force -->

Powershell exited on computer with error code 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would do this using PowerShell remoting and not psexec using

`invoke-command`

See `help invoke-command -examples` for some examples.
`invoke-command` executes a script block, so you would need to enter the content of your script in that part.

On Windows clients, you would need to enable remoting first.

But then there's the issue of double hopping. As your password can't normally be reused in a remote session. The remote host can't use your credentials in turn to contact other computers on your behalf.